# Antlr4 Match Force Priority

Tags: antlr4

I have a query grammar I am working on and have found one case that is proving difficult to solve. The below provides a minimal version of the grammar to reproduce it.

```
grammar scratch;

query : command* ; // input rule

RANGE: '..';
NUMBER: ([0-9]+ | (([0-9]+)? '.' [0-9]+));
STRING: ~([ \t\r\n] | '(' | ')' | ':' | '|' | ',' | '.' )+ ;
WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;

command
    : 'foo:' number_range                  # FooCommand
    | 'bar:' item_list                     # BarCommand
 ;

number_range: NUMBER RANGE NUMBER # NumberRange;

item_list: '(' (NUMBER | STRING)+ ((',' | '|') (NUMBER | STRING)+)* ')' # ItemList;
```

When using this you can match things like `bar:(bob, blah, 57, 4.5) foo:2..4.3` no problem. But if you put in `bar:(bob.smith, blah, 57, 4.5) foo:2..4` it will complain `line 1:8 token recognition error at: '.s'` and split it into 'bob' and 'mith'. Makes sense, `.` is ignored as part of string. Although not sure why it eats the 's'.

So, change string to `STRING: ~([ \t\r\n] | '(' | ')' | ':' | '|' | ',' )+ ;` instead without the dot in it. And now it will recognize `2..4.3` as a string instead of number_range.

I believe that this is because the string matches more character in one stretch than other options. But is there a way to force `STRING` to only match if it hasn't already matched elements higher in the grammar? Meaning it is only a `STRING` if it does not contain `RANGE` or `NUMBER`?

I know I can add `TERM: '"' .*? '"';` and then add `TERM` into the item_list, but I was hoping to avoid having to quote things if possible. But seems to be the only route to keep the `..` range in, that I have found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could allow only single dots inside strings like this:

```
STRING : ATOM+ ( '.' ATOM+ )*;

fragment ATOM : ~[ \t\r\n():|,.];
```

Oh, and `NUMBER: ([0-9]+ | (([0-9]+)? '.' [0-9]+));` is rather verbose. This does the same: `NUMBER : ( [0-9]* '.' )? [0-9]+;`